# Assignment between two maps - move semantics and performance

Tags: c++, c++11

Given the following simple program:

```
struct A { 

map<string,size_t> someMap;
};


static map<string,size_t> getMap() {
    ...
}

int main (void) {
     A s;
     s.someMap = getMap();
}
```

Does the move semantics take place here? Is that assignment efficient?
What If I had a map full of data and then assigned it with a totally new map. Is that efficient with c++11 move semantics?

thanks in advance

Comment: It will be automatically moved in both cases (provided the totally new map is the return value of a function).

Comment: It depends on what happens inside of `getMap()`. Are you instantiating a new map there and returning it?

Comment: Yes. instantiating a new map, inserting values etc and then return it.

Comment: I'd say you're very likely to get [Return value optimistaion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Return_value_optimization) happening here, even compiling in C++98 mode.

Comment: In that case, yes, you will get move assignment. If in doubt, you can always call `std::map::swap` instead.

Comment: @TristanBrindle it is an assignment though. The returned object has to be assigned to a pre-existing one.

Comment: What if there is an existing object there?

Comment: @juanchopanza Ah, true, should have spotted that, apologies

Comment: Do I force move by writing: s.someMap = std::move(getMap()); ?

Comment: @Rouki: Nothing needs to be done, the map will be moved from the local object to the class member all the way through. The return value of `getMap()` is already an rvalue, so `std::move` is superfluous.

Comment: If you want to make sure that your code is backwards compliant and avoid extra copying, the getMap function should return a const reference: static const map<string,size_t>& getMap(); The RVO optimization is great when you need to return a modified/temprary map object.

Answer (score 1):

In your case, there are two *potential* copies/moves. What happens is the follow:

When entering in `getMap()`, stack memory is allocated for a temporary `map<string, size_t>`, let's call it `tmp`. As explained in the comments to the OP, `getMap()` creates a local `map<string, size_t>` which we refer to as `orig`.

When execution reaches `return orig;`, it triggers a *potential* copy from `orig` to `tmp`. The second *potential* copy is from `tmp` to `s.someMap`.

The Standard (C++98/03 and C++11) allows the copy from `orig` to `tmp` to be elided (this is the Return Value Optimization mentioned by Tristan Brindle in the comments to the OP) by emplacing `orig` in the memory reserved for `tmp`.

Notice that the Standard allows RVO but it doesn't force it. However the major compilers (gcc, clang VS and Intel) implement RVO and no copy is made. If your compiler doesn't implement RVO then instead of a copy a move will be made from `orig` to `tmp` (unless your compiler is not C++11 compliant).

Then from `tmp` to `s.someMap` a C++11 compiler must do a move instead of a copy. Here, we can't avoid the copy/move because `s.someMap` was previously constructed and is now assigned to the result of `getMap()`. The situation would be different if you had

```
map<string,size_t> someOtherMap = getMap();
```

In this case the copy or move from `tmp` to `someOtherMap` can also be elided.

Comment: "When execution reaches `return orig;`, it triggers a potential copy from `orig` to `tmp`" -- wrong, C++11 guarantees a move.

Comment: @Xeo That's why I used the word "potential". Later in the text I say that a C++11 compiler (that doesn't implement RVO) is obliged to make a move.